# How to get a back button in google maps in Phonegap/Cordova (iOS & Android)

Tags: javascript, android, ios, google-maps, cordova

I have a Phonegap/Cordova project with a google map link. When I go to the google map page/app on Android and iOS, there is no return option to the previous page. So my question is, is it possible to display a back button in google maps to go back to my app/page?

Javascript and HTML:

```js
 function googleNavigate()
{
  window.location.href ='http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr='+ latGeo +', '+ lonGeo +'&daddr='+ latArticle +','+ lonArticle +'';
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1.0">

    <!-- Google maps Javascript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAY-ZgdUCigx5C07JP3J8VVVRFUKUSSs4A"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="navigate-button">
      <a href="#" onclick="googleNavigate()" class="button tiny navigate-button">Navigeer</a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I retrieve a latitude and longitude from the geolocator, that's the reason I put the href in javascript.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem with the childbrowser plugin and it works for Android and iOS.

Javascript:

```
function googleNavigate()
{
window.plugins.ChildBrowser.showWebPage('https://www.google.com/maps?saddr=' + latGeo + ',' + lonGeo + '&daddr=' + latArticle + ',' + lonArticle + '',
        {showLocationBar: true});
}
```

And added this to my (xml) config file:

```
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.childbrowser" version="5.0.0" />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open the native navigation app on iOS/Android (rather than the website), you can use [this cordova/phonegap plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/phonegap-launch-navigator).

On Android, pressing the hardware back button in Google Maps navigation returns your app.

On iOS, you can use the [x-callback](http://x-callback-url.com/) mechanism with [Google Maps for iOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme#specify_a_callback_url)

Answer (score 0):

Add a listener for the back button and call the function that will get you in the previous HTML page with the callback function :

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);

function onBackKeyDown() {
    // Handle the back button
     window.history.back();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply BipBip, but it's not working. I added the addEventlistener in my onDeviceReady function but I can't see a back button in google maps.

Comment: Just add it in a random place in your html page.. and the back button is the back button of your phone not an html button tag

Comment: Okay thanks, but a iPhone does not have a back button. I'am trying childbrowser right now, I will post the outcome later.

Comment: If you don't have a back button in iPhone, create a button or whatever and call the function onclick